# PHP Ajax get all links and show them one by one

Tags: php, ajax, curl, foreach, switch-statement

I want to extract all links from an website and show them one by one untill all links are scratched.

PHP

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

switch ($action) {

case 'getlinks':

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {

$info = $node->getAttribute('href');

$showresult .= '<li>'.$info.'</li>';

}

echo '<ul>'.$showresult.'</ul>'; 

break;

}
```

AJAX

```
function ajaxcall(action, div) {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url: "function.php?url=google.com&action="+ action,
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(data){

 $(div).html(data);

  }
     });

}

ajaxcall('getlinks', '.getlinks');
```

HTML

```
 <div class="getlinks"></div>
```

This code is working but showing all links in mass. I need to show loading each link inside the < ul > one by one.

Comment: You will have to need a counter to pass with each AJAX call and increment that counter in success function. Use that counter in php page to echo the correct link

Comment: But I do not need to be as effect, I need it to be real, I mean when a link is extracted to show it immediatelly.

Comment: But that is not how AJAX works it loads the server side page when the page finishes processing(in your case the loop)

Comment: I understand, but in my case how should I do ?

Comment: You want to make several AJAX calls then. Each call returning 1 link extracted.

Comment: @GeorgeGeorge Unless you find some way of returning a single link from a google search, your php will always scrape a whole page full of links and return the processed results in one response. You could introduce a pointless, artificial delay in your frontend or see if google's APIs have some functionality that'll do what you want

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your are catching with a method GET in your file on php and your ajax file is in method POST. Please try this:

```
ajaxcall('getlinks', '.getlinks');

function ajaxcall(action, div) {
    var info = 'action='+action+'&url=google.com';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "function.php",
      data: info,
      success: function(data){
            $(div).html(data);
      }
         });
}
```

Also, your switch condition is wrong. This is the correctly:

```
<?php

    $action = $POST['action'];

    switch ( $action ) :
        case 'getlinks':

        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {

        $info = $node->getAttribute('href');

        $showresult .= '<li>'.$info.'</li>';

        echo '<ul>'.$showresult.'</ul>'; 
    break;
    endswitch;

}

?>
```

Comment: Not working because you are ussing   $showresult .= The .= use it only when you save more information than only one line. Just use 
        $showresult = '<li>'.$info.'</li>'; and a print_r